# Is it possible to write a Lua parser that only cares about function definitions?

Tags: parsing, lua

I am building a set of haxe externs (AKA bindings) for Neovim APIs. However, the number of methods is huge and I am using some metaprogramming techniques to do it automatically.
I just reached the limit of what plain regular expressions can achieve, and I decided to write a proper parser. However, I don't want to build a full Lua parser, just the bare minimum to read the luaDoc comments and the function signature.
I was wondering if it is possible to build a parser that only cares about those two.
My understanding is that, in order to properly discard the parts that I am not interested on I must be able to parse them, even if it is just at the lexing step and then I just discard them during parsing.
Is any technique or anything that could let me lex/parse less?

Comment: The problem you're going to run into more is that Lua is pretty open-ended. You can create a function without giving it a name, and then assign that anonymous function a name. This makes tracking a function name difficult if the programmer wants to make it so.

Comment: That is a good point, I almost forgot about it. However, my objective is pretty focused, top level function declarations, I don't mind ignoring everything else.

Comment: I don't think you need a complete parser. Try [ltokenp](https://web.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#ltokenp) and start collecting when you see `function` and end collecting when you see `)`. This extracts function definitions. I'm not familiar with luaDoc, but ltokenp won't see comments.

Comment: I already thought about using another parser and discard the parts I am not interested on, but that is still parsing the entire Lua, right? So I think the answer to my question is NO